# how to change the background color of aonly a word of a javascript string?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $question_mark = "?";
  var $question = "They look " . concat($question_mark) . concat(" the plaining the wall ") . concat($question_mark) . concat(" the girls");
  $('.scrolling_quiz').text($question);
});
```

this code shows a string like: `They look ? the planing the wall ? the girls`

now i want to add background:blue just to the "?". not to the full sentence. Can you please send me an idea or solution to this?

Comment: You can wrap the ? by span and add color to span.

Comment: Use the deprecated font tag which is otherwise universally supported and used widely by all sorts of html generators and RTEs: `var $question_mark = "<font color=blue>?</font>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Mehdi's idea, you might have something like:

```
var $question_mark = "<span class='blue'>?</span>";
var $question = "They look " + $question_mark + " the plaining the wall " + $question_mark + " the girls";
```

And then your css will look like:

```
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
```

If you meant that you want everything *between* the ?'s to be blue, you could do this:

```
var $question_mark = "?";
var $question = "They look <span class='blue'>" + $question_mark + " the plaining the wall " + $question_mark + "</span> the girls";
```

***EDIT***

I have created a jsfiddle and fixed the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/uc42z0LL/6/

I suspect you weren't including the jquery dependency.

Comment: can you please check my link and tell why it's not working? I followed your system: jsfiddle.net/fLvo8hgc

Comment: @shaylakarzon I changed `$('.scrolling_quiz').text($question);` to `$('.scrolling_quiz').html($question);`. This way, the text you want to show is treated as HTML instead of plaintext. http://jsfiddle.net/fLvo8hgc/1/